# has_many_and_belongs_to self-join association and conditional has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, self-join

We have these 3 models:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers,
                          :class_name => "Group",
                          :foreign_key => "customer_id",
                          :association_foreign_id => "supplier_id"

  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers,
                          :class_name => "Group",
                          :foreign_key => "supplier_id",
                          :association_foreign_id => "customer_id"

  has_many :orders, :as => :orderable

  validates :name => :presence => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  has_many :orders, :as => :orderable
  belongs_to :group

  validates :email, :name, :group_id, :presence => true
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orderable, :polymorphic => true

  validates :orderable_id, :presence => true
end
```

According to the self-joined `Group` model we have 2 "types" of groups: `customers` and `suppliers`.

Now we want that the `has_many :orders, :as => :orderable` association should exist only for the `customer` group type and not for `suppliers`.

So, only a `customer` could have many orders while a `supplier` cannot have any `Order` associated.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or I have to split the `Group` model into `Customer` and `Supplier` models?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO would be better having 2 different models.

Comment: Yes... we're going there @csaura ;) thank you! You could add it as an answer and I'll be glad to accept it :)